# Simplify, equivalent for (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)

Tags: propositional-calculus

In my text book I'm asked to deduce a simpler expression for

(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)

Looking at an equivalency table I did, it seems `p ∨ ¬q` gives the same results as `(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)`. However I'm not sure how you would deduce this without the table, as in, if I was outrightly asked to write the above in simpler terms I wouldn't know where to begin. Am I understanding this correctly?

My Table:

[image: table]

Comment: You can use, for example, `a ∧ (b ∨ c)` is equivalent to `(a ∧ b) ∨ (a ∧ c)`. Check your logic identities. That's the point of the exercise.

Comment: ah I see, so would that mean `p ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)` == `(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)`

Comment: I think something is buggy in your truth table $p \vee \neg q$ is true when $p$ is true

Comment: @AriVictor no. I don't see how you got that. Look carefully again at the identity.

Comment: @KitterCatter Sorry I don't follow? I understoof `∨` to mean when either is `true`, therefore if `p` is `false` and `q` is `false`, `¬` would be `true` making `∨¬ ` `true`?

Comment: First row, $p$ is true, $\neg q$ is false so $p\vee \neg q$ should be true, you have it marked as false

Comment: @lurker right! I see, if we say a, b, c, then the three identities would be `p, ¬p, and ¬q` therefore `¬ ∧ (p ∨ ¬p) ` ?

Comment: @KitterCatter Ohh! I see now.

Comment: No. `p`, `¬p`, and `¬q` are not identities. An identity is like what I showed you in my first comment. It's a logical rule showing how one form is equivalent to another. In your case the term `(p ∨ ¬q)` would correspond to `a`.

Comment: The column for $p$ or not $q$ is incorrect. You can see it because, in the table, it is the same as not $q$, which is suspicious since $p$ or not $q$ had more possibilities of truth, so it should be true more often than not $q$.

Comment: What is the textbook? While we can show many different ways to solve this, in a course like this it's critically important to be able to cite the starting assumptions/axioms/theorems that your reasoning is based on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the corrected table:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc|c}
  P & Q & \neg P & \neg Q & P\lor\neg Q & \neg P\lor\neg Q & (P\lor \neg Q)\land(\neg P\lor \neg Q)\\\hline
 T&T&F&F&T&F&F\\
 T&F&F&T&T&T&T\\
 F&T&T&F&F&T&F\\
 F&F&T&T&T&T&T
\end{array}$$

From this, you can see that $(p \lor \neg q)\land(\neg p \lor \neg q) \iff (\neg q)$

Answer (score 22):

$$(p \lor \lnot q) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \iff (p \land \lnot p) \lor \lnot q \iff \lnot q.$$

Answer (score 5):

This is actually an instance of the following logical equivalence principle:

**Adjacency**

$(p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q) \Leftrightarrow p$

So, with this principle, you can immediately say that:

$(p \lor \neg q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q) \Leftrightarrow \neg q$

When you do boolean algebra to simplify expressions, this situation comes up a lot, so I highly recommend remembering this equivalence principle!

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth learning this as its own special fact. You can get it immediately from distribution of $\land$ and $\lor$ as in [Robert Shore's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262868/97480), without needing to know its name.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It's [very useful for automated theorem proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

Comment: @DavidRicherby To each their own I guess. I do boolean algebra a lot, and find this equivalence to be a great time-saver and insight-provider. Same with Absorption ($p \land (p \lor q) \Leftrightarrow p$) and Reduction ($p \land (\neg p \lor q) \Leftrightarrow p \land q$). Yes, they can all be derived from more basic principles, but boy, do things go faster if you have them. And, I quickly see things that others do not. Indeed, merely relying on the most elementary principles is like doing arithmetic using the Peano axioms, or programming in machine code.

Comment: @Kevin Good point :)

Comment: @Bram28 Fair enough -- I bow to your greater experience.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the following properties of boolean algebra,

\begin{align}
 a\bar{a} &=0\\
 1 a &=a\\
 0 a &=0\\
 a+\bar{a}&=1\\
 0+a &=a\\
1+a &=1\\
a+a&=a\\
a(b+c)&=ab+ac
\end{align}

you can simplify

\begin{align}
(p+\bar{q})(\bar{p}+\bar{q})
 &=p\bar{p}+ (p+\bar{p})\bar{q}+\bar{q}\bar{q}\\
 &= 0 + 1\bar{q}+\bar{q}\\
 &= 0 +\bar{q}\\
 &=\bar{q}
\end{align}

Comment: Don't you also need $aa=a$ to get from $\bar{q}\bar{q}$ to $\bar{q}$?

Comment: @pizzapants184: Yes. You are correct. I forgot to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $q$ is true one of the conjuncts will be true and the other false, and the conjunction will be false, whereas if $q$ is false both conjunts will be true, so the conjunction will be true. Since it's true iff $q$ isn't, the simplest expression for the truth-function is $\neg q$.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using propositional logic.  With some mild short-cuts for brevity, we have:

```
1.  Assume: (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)
2.  Conclude: p ∨ ¬q (from 1)
3.  Conclude: ¬p ∨ ¬q (from 1)
4.  Suppose p:
5.      Conclude ¬q (from 2,4)
6.  Conclude p → ¬q (from 4-5)
7.  Conclude ¬q ∨ ¬q (from 2, 6)
8.  Conclude ¬q (from 7)
```

I'll note that it is common to conclude 6 directly from 2.

So, this shows that `((p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)) → ¬q` .  However, now we have to ask: Does it show anything else?  Let's apply basic substitution to check:
`(p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q)`
`(p ∨ ⊤) ∧ (¬p ∨ ⊤)` (We know ¬q, so we can learn nothing further about q.  Replace ¬q with T.
`⊤ ∧ T` (Anything ∨ T) is always true, regardless of the value anything.  So that tells us nothing.

So, we can now conclude:
`p ∨ ¬p` (This is a tautology due to law of excluded middle, so it can remain unstated)
`¬q`

An even simpler proof would be proof by contradiction (i.e., assume q, then get `(p) ∧ (¬p)`).  This is the approach taken by [J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3263330/3862)